# Dosso case in Pakistan

Tags: criminal-law, constitutional-law, bail, pakistan

In 1958, a man named Dosso (who lacked a surname), was convicted of murder in Baluchistan under section 302 of the Pakistan Penal Code by a Loya Jirga (a tribal court). An appeal was made to the Pakisatn Supreme court. Is the Loya Jirga able to sue to court to maintain is decision's value and worth, and could that decision could be reversed or not?

Sources used in the edit: http://nasirlawsite.com/historic/pld533.htm
http://www.cssforum.com.pk/css-optional-subjects/group-vi/constitutional-law/98162-state-v-s-dosso-case-updated.html

Comment: Close voters and down voters: please explain your votes, so that the question can be improved. Particularly close voters. It seems like a perfectly valid question (especially in light of the answer user6726 has provided), albeit one that could use a little cleaning up for readability.

Comment: @sharur I haven't down voted but close-voted as "unclear". I still can't really understand the question, but clearly you and user6726 were able to. If either of you could edit the question to be more readable/understandable, that would be great.

Comment: @DPenner1: Fair enough, I will try to make the question more readable (I didn't actually edit the question previously, just added more tags).

Comment: @MuhammadMehboob: I have edited your question to make it more clear. I hope that I have preserved the question you wished to ask (a very interesting one from what I have found). Please let me know if this still asks the question you wish to have answered, if not please roll back my changes or make additions of your own with the "edit" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Loya Jirga is essentially an inferior court: their judgment was [overturned by the High Court](http://www.cssforum.com.pk/css-optional-subjects/group-vi/constitutional-law/98162-state-v-s-dosso-case-updated.html). There is no appeal beyond that. You can read the ruling [here](http://nasirlawsite.com/historic/pld533.htm): the underlying issue regards continuity of law in the face of a coup and nullified constitution (the Frontier Crimes Regulation was void, the conviction was without jurisdiction).